# How do you put a grid in a column in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've read the docs and watched some tutorials but can't figure out how to get exactly what I need. I will try to explain. I tried to post screen shots, but it said you have to have 10 reputation.

So for a large screen it should be 3 rows with 4 columns each. The third column in the second row should be divided into another grid that is identical to the big grid, 3 rows, 4 columns.

On mobile it should be one big column with the seventh one being the smaller grid.

Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <script src="lib/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <title>Untable</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container"> 
        <h3>Untable</h3>
        <p>Convert this 'table-based' design into a 'responsive bootstrap grid' design.</p>
        <p>Add whatever css and javascript you need to accomplish this.</p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">One</div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">Two</div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">Three</div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">Four</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">Five</div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">Six</div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
              <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-3">One</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-3">Two</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-3">Three</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-3">Four</div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-3">One</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-3">Two</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-3">Three</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-3">Four</div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-3">One</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-3">Two</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-3">Three</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-3">Four</div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">Eight</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">Nine</div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">Ten</div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">Eleven</div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">Twelve</div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Additional CSS:

```
 .container-fluid {

    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
}

.container {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Edit: Well my reputation is 10 now (haha). So here is what I am trying to accomplish.

### Mobile

[image]

### Desktop

[image]

Comment: Your code seems to be fine.

Comment: You code looks fine to me it shrinks to full width when in mobile

Answer (score 0):

So what you're trying to do is totally possible - and you're on the right track to do it!

The most important thing to remember with bootstrap is to treat every 'col' as a brand-new section to work within. With that in mind, you can design with bootstrap on different *levels* and it will usually work as intended.

So in your case, the two levels to consider would be:

1. The top-level 12 columns, no matter what is in each one
2. Whatever is inside the 7th column

So for 1, you've approached it correctly! Simple set up your rows with the maximum number of columns you even plan to have in them as child-elements. As your greatest number is four in a row, you can totally do three rows with four columns in each (exactly as you did)!

For 2, again, you have the right approach. You would once again define three rows with three columns. However, this time you need to remember that you want those to STILL be in a 4-column per row configuration on xs size. As it is now, you have them re-sizing just like the top level columns, so when they are on an xl screen, they will each be full width. Instead, just give each column element in the second element a col-xs-3 class. That way they will always be aligned in the 'table format' you're looking for - even on a small screen size.

Example:

```
<div className="container-fluid">

   <div className="row">
      <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
         One
      </div>
      <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
         Two
      </div>
      <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
         Three
      </div>
      <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
         Four
      </div>
   </div>

   <div className="row">
      <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
         Five
      </div>
      <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
         Six
      </div>
      <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-3">

         <div className="row">
            <div className="col-xs-3">
               Sub One
            </div>
            <div className="col-xs-3">
               Sub Two
            </div>
            <div className="col-xs-3">
               Sub Three
            </div>
            <div className="col-xs-3">
               Sub Four
            </div>
         </div>

         <div className="row">
            <div className="col-xs-3">
               Sub One
            </div>
            <div className="col-xs-3">
               Sub Two
            </div>
            <div className="col-xs-3">
               Sub Three
            </div>
            <div className="col-xs-3">
               Sub Four
            </div>
         </div>

      </div>
      <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
         Eight
      </div>
   </div>

</div>
```

And that's it! You've got this :)